# (Discord Python Bot) How do I edit a role's permissions?

Tags: python, bots, discord, edit, roles

I'm trying to make my bot go through all the roles and change their permissions so they cannot embed or send images. I can grab all the roles just fine by doing

```
for role in message.guild.roles:
```

But how do I use the edit() function to set these permissions to false?

The API is pretty hard to follow on the matter [ https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Permissions ]

bump